# ClickOnce Install, Cant Find Included Mdb Data File for backup restore function

Tags: vb.net

Respected Sir,

Using ClickOnce to deploy an application with a mdb database as Data File. And when trying to backup mdb database file, it does backup in testing enviorments debug or release. But once the application is installed by clickonce, it says unable to find database file. Any error in script ?

```
Private Sub myBackupFunctionOne()
        'Get the database path
        Dim CurrentDatabasePath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\myDB.mdb"

        Dim fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog()

        If fbd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'Set the path where you want to store the backup file
            Dim PathtobackUp As String = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString()

            System.IO.File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, PathtobackUp & "\BackUp.MDB", True)

            MessageBox.Show("Back Up SuccessFull! ")
        End If
    End Sub
```

yours faithfully

Murulimadhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickOnce stores data files in a special folder.  You can detect whether an application is ClickOnce-deployed at run time and get that folder path if it is or use the program folder path if it's not, e.g.

```
Dim dataDirectoryPath = If(ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed,
                           ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory,
                           Application.StartupPath)
Dim databaseFilePath = Path.Combine(dataDirectoryPath, "data.mdb")
```

Note the fact that I have used `Application.StartupPath` for the prgram folder rather than `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.  The path returned by `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can change over the course of a session and may not even start as the program folder, so it is a bad option to use in this case.  `Application.StartupPath`, on the other hand, can never change and will always return the folder from which the current application was run.